# Since iOS 7 SDK, UIButton suddenly becomes dark when highlighted

Tags: uibutton, ios7

A UIButton with a custom background image for normal and highlighted states, suddenly became dark when highlighted, after migrating to iOS 7 SDK.

`adjustsImageWhenHighlighted` was set to NO and it was working fine up until the new SDK.

Button is defined in a XIB and being assigned with text later in code.

What was changed?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It turns out that during the migration, the interface builder changed the button type from Custom into System.

System buttons do this behaviour, even when `adjustsImageWhenHighlighted` is turned off.

After changing button type back to `Custom`, issue was fixed.